# "Each person's car" vs. "each persons' car"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, orthography, possessives, apostrophe

Which of the following is correct?

> - Each **person's** car has four wheels.
> - Each **persons'** car has four wheels.

Comment: Reasons to **keep open**: (1) It's a common misunderstanding (2) Lots of [inquiries](https://www.google.com/search?q=each+apostrophe) lead here (3) the answer merits explanation (4) the answers today are too brief or too technical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Each" refers to a singular. Hence, it should be:

> Each person's car has four wheels.

Answer (score 8):

First off, the correct answer is "each person's".

Why? *each* is a determiner of English representing universal quantification. This quantifier states that a predicate is true for everything or everything of a particular subset. Here, the set is all cars and the predicate is something like "x has four wheels". This can then be formalized to something like: ∀xP(x), x∈{cars} and P(x)=x has four wheels. The nature of this quantification means that x must be singular in number. If it helps, think of a `foreach` loop in various programming languages.

The *'s* is a different issue. Without delving too much into X-Bar theory, here's a simple explanation. The *'s* too is actually a determiner and is dominated by the first [Determiner Phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase). For example, a simple model:

> [DP each person [DP 's car]].

This matches other languages (like German) nicely where the genitive is still represented by a "full" word. This also lets you get away with wild things like: "[the man who lives over by the field and has red hair]'s car has four wheels."

Comment: Can you clarify what DP means in "dominated by the first DP"?

Comment: Sure thing–a bit out of scope of the answer, but added some Google terms and links.

Comment: (re: wild things) or, more canonically, "The Queen of England's hat".