# "Each country's dances are different" or Each countries' dances are different"?

Tags: grammar

Each country's dances are different or Each countries' dances are different?

Comment: *Each country's dances are different.* "Each" is singular.

Comment: "Every country's dance is different."

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Each person's car" vs. "each persons' car"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351/each-persons-car-vs-each-persons-car)

Answer (score 2):

"Each country's dances" or "all countries' dances" are your options. "*Each countries' dances" is not an option.

Comment: 'Twould be like saying 'Each men's trousers are ragged'!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the possessive, you could reword it as "The dances of each country are different". You wouldn't say "The dances of each countries are different", though, so the first one you list is the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

"Each countries' dances are different" is wrong according to English Grammar. You can use "Each country's dances are different".